# Spring form errors with multiple identical forms on the same page

Tags: forms, spring, validation, path

I am printing an **arbitrary** number of identical forms on a page using Spring's `<form:form` tag, and I need a way to distinguish between them, because form errors of one form are now printed on all forms.

Currently all the identical forms are bound to the same, single backing object. That works fine, because a user can only submit one form at a time.

I am using Spring validation to validate form fields. When one of the fields has an error (let's say 'name' is empty) than the error message is printed under the 'name' field of all forms.

Obviously, I need some way to allow Spring to distinguish between the forms, but how?

Some example code:

This Spring webflow definition creates a ClientFormBacking object to back the client forms. And it submits a form POST to the bindAndValidate method, which calls the validator.

```
<webflow:var name="clientFormBacking" class="com.example.ClientFormBacking"/>
<webflow:view-state id="list" view="clients" model="clientFormBacking">
    <webflow:on-entry>
        <webflow:evaluate expression="contextParameterManager.findAll()" result="flowScope.clients"/>
    </webflow:on-entry>
    <webflow:transition on="update-client" to="list">
        <webflow:evaluate expression="clientBinder.bindAndValidate(flowRequestContext)"/>
        <webflow:evaluate expression="clientService.saveOrUpdate(flowScope.clientsPageBacking)"/>
    </webflow:transition>
</webflow:view-state>
```

Print an arbitrary number of identical forms with a name field and name error field in JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${clients} var="client">
    <form:form commandName="clientFormbacking">
        <form:input path='name' value='${client.name}'/>
        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="input-error" />
    </form:form>
</c:forEach>
```

The validator that rejects the 'name' field:

```
ClientValidator implements Validator {

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        // Problem here! There are multiple <form:errors path='name'/> tags....
        errors.rejectValue("name", "validation.error.name.empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: They all share the same `commandName` (modelAttribute) so what would expect?

Comment: So do you know a way to tie an arbitrary number of backing objects to an arbitrary number of identical forms in Spring webflow? Or maybe another solution?

Comment: They should all have their own backing object. But I wonder if this approach defeats the whole purpose of having a web flow. I mean, a flow should break up complex forms and gather information along the way. I don't really see how multiple forms on one page fit into this picture.

Comment: Granted, Spring webflow is not suited for this case, but I am currently unable to divert from it for non-technical reasons. I might initialize a collection of backing objects by overriding FormAction.setupForm(). I am currently investigating that. Will get back with the solution if it works.

Comment: Currently how are the forms in the page? show some code.